# Dsiplaying content with taildwindcss doesn't give me the wanted render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I would like to display my textareas into 3 columns with gap between them. I've tried to give this style to my container `flex flex-row flex-wrap` but then  `grid grid-cols-3 gap-10`. BUT obviously, if I make the window too small then the 3 columns will move down or up because flex-wrap property is set to wrap (because I need row and columns to be on separate lines).

Can someone see what I have to do please ?

Here a picture to get the idea : [image]

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-wiles-e08ldl?file=/src/Display.jsx)

Comment: You don't have `tailwind` installed, follow the installation guide for CRA https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: @PabloSilió, I've installed is it better ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no tailwind config file in the repo, and it's not included in the CSS. You need to do steps 3 and 4 in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app, and install postcss and autoprefixer too.